# Why I can't create laravel projects anymore?

Tags: php, laravel, github, openssl, composer-php

I am working on a local server on my windows os,
I used to be able to create new laravel projects normally, but now I keep getting errors like these:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>laravel new blog
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 70 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download doctrine/inflector from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/inflector/zipball/5527a48b7313d15261292c149e55e26eae771b0a" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Cloning 5527a48b73 from cache
```

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6870 -- A lot of people have said it's Kaspersky antivirus, or you may just need to update your certificates for GitHub.

Comment: that must be a joke, it was kaspersky. I turned it off and everything worked smoothly. thanks aynber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure your internet connection not have problem in speed
so check your firewall not blocked    api.github.com    url